# How to show seleted option with group label on dropdown using optgroup in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

This is my code

```html
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="myOption">
    <optgroup label="Emplopyee">
    <option value="Id">id</option>
<option value="Name">Name</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Department">
    <option value="Id">id</option>
<option value="Name">Name</option>
    </optgroup>    
    </select>
  <div>
```

In the above code when select the option id from Employee Label shows Id on dropdown , but i want to show Employee.Id on dropdown

Comment: There is also ambiguity in HTML select element with two optgroup having same value. when such duplicate value in two optgroup is selected, it is not clear which duplicate value is selected from which optgroup.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but a scenario:-

User has to select a city from few countries,
Country>>
   Cities

US

- San Jose
- Washington
- New York

Mexico

- Guadalajara
- Iztapalapa
- San Jose

When we select San Jose from Mexico, and get value of select element, then we get 'San Jose', but info about the group is not available.

How to get value like Mexico.San Jose, without using id attribute on the option elements.